# Terminal vim shortcut in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, gvim

How can I create a shortcut to open a terminal and launch vim (terminal version, not gvim) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut with `gnome-terminal -e vim` as the target.

Answer (score 0):

Look up in the options of your favourite terminal and see which allows you to run a given program. Using xterm:

```
xterm -e vim
```

assuming that `vim` is in you `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a keyboard shortcut then typing vi or vim in when terminal opens:
[Bind terminal to a key combination](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-a-hotkey-to-open-a-terminal-window-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

using an alias in your .bash_rc file, e.g.

```
alias tvim="gnome-terminal -e vim"
```

if you use gnome-terminal obviously